# haproxy/jetty - redirect all unknown path_beg

Tags: haproxy, jetty

i have configured valid domains and paths e.g.
`http://submdomain.host.com/validpath1`
`http://submdomain.host.com/validpath2`

this is identified redirected by:
`acl url_monitor path_beg /Monitor/
use_backend monitor if url_monitor`

request coming to non recognised path_beg:
`http://submdomain.host.com/unknownpath1
http://submdomain.host.com/unknownpath2`

i'm getting the next error

HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /unknown1. Reason:
    Not Found
Powered by Jetty://

i want to redirect all unknown ACL instead to:
`http://submdomain.host.com/support or http://support.host.com`

nbe222

Answer (score 2):

well if you have list of all valid urls as you said create an acl for valid urls like

```
acl valid_path path_beg -i /path1 path_beg -i /path2 path_beg -i /path3 path_beg -i /path4

http-request redirect location http://submdomain.host.com/support if !valid_path
```